# flutter await GET response is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the follow function:

```
 Future<Null> _loadORDER(String menssage) async {

      var enZona =await ApiClient.zonaNum(menssage, apiKey);
      print('enZona: $enZona');
      if (enZona == 'true') {
        _moveToNotification(context);
      };
    }
```

the print give me the follow message: "enZona: Instance of 'Response'"

if i test the response from **postman** of the api query is working normally and give me:  **true** ,
then i hope that the print result will be : "enZona: true"

but i don't know how i do to wait the response of the ApiClient before continue with the conditional (if)

thanks for your help!

thanks i add the .body but i get the same response, the apiclient code is the follow:

```
 final response = await http.get(baseUrl + '/shop/order/$message',
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: apiKey});
    print("enZona: $response.body");
    return response;
```

the print value for this is:   **enZona: Instance of 'Response'.body**

Comment: thanks i add the .body but i get the same response, i added the apiclient code

Comment: clean and build your code.

Comment: you should do print("enZona: ${response.body}"); with the curly bracket, or you can assign response.body to some variable first. final foo = response.body;
print(foo);

Comment: thank you so much @Xion, this was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `print("enZona: ${response.body}");` with the curly bracket, or you can assign response.body to some variable first.

```
final foo = response.body; print(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [pub.dev documentation for the Response class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html), you will see that `Response` is more than the content of the response. It is a wrapper class that also includes information such as the `statusCode` of the response, the `headers`, etc.

When you saw the response in Postman, you only cared about the content of the response, that is, the `body` of the response. What you are looking for in your code is not the `enZona` instance of `Response`, but the `body` of the `enZona` response.

Therefore, you have to swap `enZona` by `enZona.body` when trying to access the contents of your response.